# Not a code reference in Perl class

Tags: perl, oop

I'm stumped. I'm new to Perl and after reading some articles, I still can't figure this one out. It's a very small class.

```
package Haha;

sub new {
    $class = shift;

    $self = {
        path => shift
    };

    bless $self, $class;

    return $self;
}

sub setPath {
    my ($self, $new_path) = shift;
    $self->(path) = $new_path if defined $new_path;
    return $self->(path);
}

sub getPath {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->(path);
}

1;
```

And I used it like this:

```
use lib 'lib';
use Haha;

my $new_excel = new Haha("sample path");

print $new_excel->getPath() ;

<>;
```

Class Haha line 23 raises the "Not a code reference" error.
The line that says `return $self->(path);`

Comment: Please add `use strict; use warnings` to your files and define lexical variables with `my`. Also use curly brackets and not parenthesis when accessing  object hash fields: `$self->{path} = $new_path`

Comment: `$self->(path)` implies $self is code reference; `$self->{path}` => hash reference; `$self->path` => blessed object invoking `path()` method. Please check https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your class (like most Perl classes) is implemented on top of hashes. When you create a new object in your constructor, you do it like this:

```
sub new {
    $class = shift;

    $self = {
        path => shift
    };

    bless $self, $class;

    return $self;
}
```

The line `$self = { ... }` creates an anonymous hash and stores a reference to that hash in `$self`. So, `$self` is a hash reference. Which means that you should access its contents using hash syntax. So your accessor and mutator methods are wrong.

```
sub setPath {
    my ($self, $new_path) = shift;
    $self->(path) = $new_path if defined $new_path;
    return $self->(path);
}
```

You are using parentheses, not braces, to access the `path` value in your hash. The line:

```
$self->(path) = $new_path if defined $new_path;
```

Should be:

```
# Note: braces, not parentheses
$self->{path} = $new_path if defined $new_path;
```

And the line:

```
return $self->(path);
```

Should be:

```
# Note: braces, not parentheses
return $self->{path};
```

You need to make a similar fix to `getPath()`.

Unfortunately, the syntax `$reference->($value)` is completely valid. It means "call the subroutine that you have a reference to in `$reference`, passing it `$value`". But, of course, this requires `$reference` to contain a subroutine reference, not a hash reference.

A few other suggestions.

1. Always `use strict` and `use warnings`.
2. Indirect object notation (`$new_excel = new Haha("sample path")`) is likely to burn you at some point. Please use `$new_excel = Haha->new("sample path")` instead.
3. Your line `my ($self, $new_path) = shift` doesn't do what you think it does. You want `my ($self, $new_path) = @_`.

Answer (score 0):

`path` is an attribute of the object, use curly brackets:

```
sub getPath {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{path};
}
```

In the sub `setPath`, the variable `$new_path` is never assigned, use instead:

```
sub setPath {
    my ($self, $new_path) = @_;
    $self->{path} = $new_path if defined $new_path;
    return $self->{path};
}
```

Comment: Pedantically, it's not the fact that `path` is an attribute that means you need to use braces to access it. It's the fact that the class is implemented as a hash reference. It's quite possible (tho', admittedly, rare) to implement a class as a different type of reference - in which case different types of bracket would be used.